# How to create, sign, and send a transaction using electrum wallet RPC

Tags: electrum, electrum-console

How to create, sign, and send a transaction using electrum wallet RPC ?

I have experience create/sign/send a transaction using bitcoind wallet since I just have to using bitcoind RPC. But on electrum I couldn’t find that the RPC command to do that.

The only thing I want is send bitcoin from electrum wallet but from specific addresses.